# Excel VBA import several TXT file delimited text into sheet

Tags: excel, vba, import, txt

i have a folder which contains several TXT files. each txt file has the following type of content:

```
NAME | CITY | AGE 
john | ohio | 16
wayne | texas | 37
linda | miami | 28
```

the content is delimited by the " | " parameter.
I used the macro recorder to record a manual import of one txt file via the "data / get external data /from text file" commands in the ribbon of excel. I used the recorded code in order to make a macro that automatically imports all TXTs in the folder, however i'm getting errors. Here is my code (requires to activate microsoft scripting runtime):

```
Sub ImportarTXTAExcel()
'requiere activar MICROSOFT SCRIPTING RUNTIME para el filesystemobject
Dim arrayarchivos As Variant
Dim archivoruta As Variant
Dim soloNombreArchivo As String
Dim hoja As Worksheet
Dim ultimafila As Long

Set hoja = ActiveSheet

arrayarchivos = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
                    MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Selecciona los archivos TXT que se importaran a excel")

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject

For Each archivoruta In arrayarchivos
    soloNombreArchivo = FSO.GetBaseName(archivoruta)
    ultimafila = hoja.Cells(hoja.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    'THIS PART IS FROM THE MACRO RECORDER, only introduced the variables ultimafila, archivoruta and solonombrearchivo
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;archivoruta", Destination:= _ 
        Range("A" & ultimafila))
        '.CommandType = 0 'in a forum they suggest this line can be omitted or commented since it was returning ERROR: invalid argument or call to procedure
        .Name = soloNombreArchivo
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|" 'this is the delimiter
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 'ERROR comes at this line
    End With
   
Next archivoruta
MsgBox "todos los txt se han importado a excel"

End Sub
```

the error comes at the .refresh background line, i'm getting the following message:
'''1004 runtime error. Can't find the text file to update this external data range. check that the file hasn't changed its name or was moved'''

Upon checking the excel file, no information is imported. Already tried commenting that particular line, and the macro throws no errors, but doesn't import anything as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `"TEXT;archivoruta"` looks off. Variables don't belong inside quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply BigBen. You're right, i replaced the following line `"TEXT; archivoruta "` with `" TEXT; " & archivoruta` and now the macro seems to work fine.